# Consumo API com Fetch js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando consumir a API do governo federal sobre o auxilio emergência.
O meu problema é quando faço a fetch, me é retornado esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código:

```
async function buscar() {
    var link = 'http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/auxilio-emergencial-por-cpf-ou-nis?codigoBeneficiario=0000&pagina=1';
    var head = new Headers();
    head.append('chave-api-dados', 'codchave');
    head.append('Accept', '*/*');
    head.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    head.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var req = new Request(link, {
        headers: head,
    });
    let data = await fetch(req);
    let da = await data.json();
    console.log(da);
}
```

Comment: Erro de _CORS_ significa que você está tentando consumir uma API de outro domínio, mas essa API não é publica, e também não está concedendo permissão ao seu domínio. Aparentemente você tentou adicionar no seu cabeçalho o `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, mas não é a sua requisição que precisa desse cabeçalho, é a resposta do servidor que precisa dela, então o que você fez não vai adiantar nada. Para consumir essa API você terá que fazer a requisição via o seu servidor, e não via o front-end do website, pois política de _CORS_ só se aplica a navegadores.

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos, e como faço essa requisição via servidor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bom...como não houve alguém que pudesse orientar, fui atrás da resposta. O problema era o fetch, o fetch é interpretado pelo browser, e eu estava fazendo no back-end. a solução simples é usar o axios, assim a requisição é feita pelo servidor no back-end retornando assim o json com as informações que necessito.

Answer (score -1):

Agora isso já é possível de ser feito no backend. De maneira nativa, sem a utilização de bibliotecas externas.

Desde o nodejs v17.5.0 (como experimental, ativado via flag) ou nativamente desde o nodejs v18.0.0. Aqui a [`release note`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/) com a notícia, procurar por `fetch`.

Segue um exemplo de chamada utilizando esta api:

```
const URL = `https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=${process.env.OPENEXCHANGEAPITOKEN}`;

exports.cotacao = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const resultado = await fetch(URL)
        req.oexchange = await resultado.json()
        res.status(200).json(req.oexchange)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({errors: [{ location: 'cotacao', msg: 'Houve um erro ao acessar a api do open exchange.', param: 'openexchangerates' }]})
    }
};
```

aqui está a minha definição de rota:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const cotacaoService = require('../services/cotacao.service');

router.get('/cotacao', cotacaoService.cotacao);

module.exports = router;
```

Isso pode ser feito sem a instalação de nenhuma biblioteca externa (de terceiros, tipo o axios, node-fetch etc...).

Existem mais exemplos de utilização do [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) no MDN.